# Constipation problem in two months pregnancy

Tags: pregnancy

i am two months pregnant. Feeling constipation every two days. What should i take to get relieved of this problem? Pls somebody advice.

Comment: What's your diet like? Diet as in food intake, do you eat fresh fruit and veggies or are you a fast food addict? Do you smoke, drink coffee, skip breakfast? It all depends.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE. What doctors normally recommend for decreasing constipation applies here as well: more fresh vegetables and less highly processed foods (as @Mari-Lou A stated), lots of fluids, regular exercise, prune juice, pear juice, etc. If that doesn't help, talk to your doctor. This is common in pregnancy, so they should have some good advice. Again, welcome.

Comment: Depending on your area, pear juice, as @anongoodnurse suggests, may be hard to find, but it's *much* more pleasant than prune juice. For us, we've only ever been able to find it in the infant sections of grocery stores and markets, so I'd recommend checking those spots to see if it's available in your area!

Answer (score 5):

As you want something for "long" term, not just for a given crisis, the dietetic solution likely is the best one.

Eating more fibers and fluids is usually the answer though depending on the person you need more soluble or insoluble fibers.

Most people need more soluble fibers (whole cereals, vegetable skins and fruits) for some though insoluble fibers will help, in this case Beans/lentils/split peas are completely outstanding in terms of fiber content.

My wife had extreme constipation and we tried both diets high in one or the other for two days, in both cases with a lot of water and we knew right away that beans was the answer. For my mother, whole wheat is the answer.

If it doesn't get better after trying both you should definitely see a dietician or a doctor for a personalized check of your general health and diet.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE. Good advice!

Answer (score 0):

Constipation is one among the most common concerns affecting women during pregnancy.diet, side effects of medications, heavy metal toxicity, hypothyroidism and hormonal disorders are some factors causing this constipation.
During this constipation,your stools are hard and difficult to pass.

Natural Ways To Tackle Constipation:

Exercises are known to stimulate the bowel as well as to improve digestion,But make sure to get guidance from expert or practice under a certified trainer.
Fresh fruits and raw vegetables are the best foods to include in your diet during this time.
Make sure you keep up with your water content throughout the day during this time and stay hydrated.

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem during pregnancy is constipation. Causes of constipation during pregnancy may be:

- hormonal changes, which makes digestive system sluggish
- consumption of oral iron tablets
- dehydration, stress
- enlargement of uterus and pelvic pain.

Try these natural remedies to relieve constipation

1. It is very important to keep your body hydrated during pregnancy. Which can help in easy bowel movements.
2. Drink warm lemon water everyday in the morning, it can help boost your bowel movements.
3. cabbage is an amazing source of fiber, It is very good to treat constipation. Drink cabbage soup to regularize bowel movements.
4. Drinking a glass of warm milk before going to bed also helps to relieve from constipation.
5. Yogurt also helps to treat constipation problem effectively

Here are some natural ways to get relief from constipation. I hope this will help you http://www.momjunction.com/articles/natural-ways-to-tackle-constipation-during-pregnancy_0083681/